# sql ssrs returning multiple selected @parameter

Tags: sql, parameters, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-expression, ssrs-2016

I have a multi value parameter which is a combined string of two fields with a space separating them i.e productID productName.

I want to pass just the parameter with just the id portion only.

I tried the expression:
=join (left (fields!productID.value,inStr (fields!productID.value," ")-1)),',') or something to that effect (sorry on mobile)

And report builder complained. Can anyone suggest a better way to write a working expression? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That Join expression does not contain the Parameter. Those are Fields from a data table. Also, what was the error?

Comment: I have to come back to you on that only posted this cuz I was tossing n turning in my sleep...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 fields in a parameter:

1. **Value Field**: will be passed and processed in back-end
2. **Label Field**: will be displayed in front-end

For Example: you can display Monthname like `January` (Label) but the value that will work in back-end is `1` (Value).

Similarly, assuming you are populating the parameter from Dataset query, following below way can fulfill your need.

[image]

Comment: Ahhh its not exactly what i'm looking for but it highlighted where I went wrong! I combined my values in the dataset when could've done it your way! Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, it looks like it does not turn the parameter into a multi valued parameter, so I am back to square one.

Comment: where are you using the multi-value expression? Any error message?

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't return an error, just that when loaded in chrome, its a drop down list where you can select one value only instead of the multiple ticks for multi-value. Where when I set any parameter with multi value allowed, it does allow it to be multi selected. Hope that clears it up.

Comment: hmmm it looks like must be an issue with my report as when i built a brand new one its fine. Thanks for your help (apologies been busy at work so didn't get to test more)

Comment: go to the general tab in the Report Parameter Properties and make sure the Allow Multiple values checkbox is checked.